# Do you move forwards or backwards on the King's Cross Chance card?

Tags: monopoly

[image: Take a trip to King’s Cross station]

If you draw the "Take a trip to King's Cross Station" Chance card, do you move your piece forwards or backwards?  The logical answer might be forwards because most Monopoly Chance cards say "advance".  However, in the case of this card, it says "If you pass go"; you would always pass go when moving forwards from a Chance space to King's Cross, so what’s the use of the word "if"?

Note: This is London Edition Monopoly; this space and card are the equivalent of Reading Railroad and the "Take a ride on the Reading" Chance card in standard edition.

Comment: Most of the cards that move you to a specific property have this text.  The only exceptions are the Mayfair / Boardwalk card and the Go To Jail card, the latter of which explicitly states that you don't pass Go.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  One of the issues with this card is that it doesn't say "Advance", and there is the additional confusion of "if you pass go"

Comment: @Zags I agree. The other question is about how to define "nearest", this one is about which direction you move.

Comment: It still is a duplicate as you still will always move in one direction in the game and they have the pass go on there as a reminder to collect it when you pass go. and both answers state movement is only forward just like in the duplicate one

Comment: @JoeW The linked question wasn't asking at all about which direction you moved; both of the 2 options the asker listed involved moving forward. It was a question of which station was considered the closest. This question is about which direction you move.

Answer (score 9):

Movement in Monopoly is always forwards (in the direction of the arrow on the Go space) unless otherwise specified (such as the "Go back three spaces card").  The only exception in regular monopoly is going to jail, which is usually written as "go directly to jail" to signify the difference.

Some older editions of monopoly had a much clearer version of this card (noting that Reading Railroad is the equivalent of King's Cross):

> Take a ride on the Reading. **Advance token** and if you pass Go, collect $200.

It is impossible to get to King's Cross/Reading Railroad from a Chance space without passing Go.  It says "if you pass Go" because that's the way all the other Chance cards are worded.  This card would be clearer if it said "when you pass go, collect $200" or "collect $200 for passing go".

Comment: "Movement in Monopoly is always forwards": I remember owning a Monopoly with a card which said "Go back to Old Kent Road."

Comment: @Angew Good point.  there is also one card in modern monopoly that specifies backwards movement.  I've updated the answer

Comment: It is however possible to draw this chance card and *not* pass Go, by landing on the first community chest space and drawing "pay $10 or take a Chance"

Comment: @Caleth What version of Monopoly is that community chest card in?  It's not in classic.

Comment: The UK version (so it's £10)

Answer (score 2):

Movement is forward in Monopoly, so you'll always pass Go (and collect 200). There *is* a Community Chest between Go and King's Cross Station, but this is a Chance card.

I *think* that it's printed this way to match the other 'Take a trip' cards, which all have this wording (except for the Mayfair card, when it's not possible to pass Go). Introducing a third variation like 'You pass Go, collect 200.' would increase the cognitive load.

Answer (score 2):

Basically when you draw any card which tells you to go to a specific place just ignore the "if you pass Go, collect $200" and go to that place, moving forward,and if you pass Go, collect the $200.

This will make the instruction on the card less confusing.

Note that if the card is "Go back 3 spaces", or "Go back to Old Kent Road/Mediterranean Avenue", then you go back and since you do not pass Go, you do not collect $200.

Answer (score 2):

Hasbro owns the copyright on Monopoly and have the final word on Monopoly rules. Concerning the movement of tokens following a Chance card instruction, the answer provided to me by Hasbro's customer service is the following:
[image: Hasbro's response]

Answer (score 0):

It says "If you pass Go" because it does not know where your piece is on the board and is standard text included on all movement cards except jail in order to remind the player of this rule redundantly.

You are moving forwards when you move to the space because there is literally no indication or mention whatsoever that one might move backwards.

Comment: Can you quote from the rules to back up your second statement (“forwards” is meant)? Would it be appropriate to add “presumably” or “probably” to the first statement?

Comment: No, but the quote was provided by OP.