# Can you pass GO backward?

Tags: monopoly

There are some reasons in Monopoly that your piece might be moving backward.  Picking up "Go back to Xyz Road"

The word "Pass" doesn't have an implicit direction, it just means to go from one side to the other side.

Its possible you might pass GO while doing so, but in reverse.  Since you're passing GO, do you collect the $200?   Or only while travelling clockwise around the board?

Inspired by [In Monopoly, if your Community Chest card reads "Go back to ...." , do you move forward or backward?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/53497/in-monopoly-if-your-community-chest-card-reads-go-back-to-do-you-move)

Comment: In the version of Monopoly I know, the only 'Go back to' card sent you back to the first space on the board. There was no way you could pass through the Go space on that route. Is there any edition of Monopoly where this would actually matter?

Comment: Does the arrow on the Go space not indicate that the you should collect your «salary» only when passing Go in the arrow's direction?

Comment: Voting to close for failing to state an example of where the answers would be relevant. (See first comment for details.)

Comment: Turns out this is a variation on https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/47257/32019 and should be closed as a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - this situation can't arise in Monopoly as long as the normal official rules are being followed.

The text on the chance card says

> Go back to Old Kent Road 
> Do not pass GO.

Since Old Kent Road is the very first property, there is nowhere you can go back to it and pass GO.

All movement is in the direction of the GO arrow, unless you're instructed to go "backward"

[image]

If there are strange house-rules then that's up to the house to decide what happens.